# copy certain files from a tree of folders?

Tags: powershell, odoo

I am trying to copy a group of files in a tree like folders into one folder to make some changes then to set them back again into their original location. for example:

```
Parent Directory\addons\account\i18n\ar.po
Parent Directory\addons\account_asset\i18n\ar.po
Parent Directory\addons\account_budget\i18n\ar.po
Parent Directory\addons\account_followup\i18\ar.po
Parent Directory\addons\account_accountant\i18n\ar.po
Parent Directory\addons\account_analytic_analysis\i18n\ar.po
```

so I want to collect ar.po files while keeping the information each file path. so I can make changes to them then restore them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are performing the modifications of the files programmatically, you can use this approach:

```
$parent = "some parent folder name"
$workdir = "some work folder name"
$filter = "ar.po"

Get-ChildItem -path $parent -Filter $filter -Recurse |% {
    Copy-Item $_.fullname $workdir

    <Do some work on the file>

    Copy-Item "$workdir\$filter" $_.fullname -Force
}
```